# How can I create connected multiple blockchains?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, connections, polkadot, raiden

I want to create multiple private blockchains over Ethereum testnet, which need to be somehow connected. Is it possible to have a node on private blockchain that is connected to the another node on another blockchain?

Edited, added details: The idea is having separate but connected blockchains. That would be enough to having only one "head" node in a blockchain connected to to other "head" node on another blockchain. Other nodes in blockchains will operate exactly as if normal private blockchain nodes. The idea is being able to somehow tracing over different blockchains, via "head" nodes in addition to tracing through same blockchain.

Comment: to do what exactly?

Comment: The idea is having separate but connected blockchains. That would be enough to having only one "head" node in a blockchain connected to to other "head" node on another blockchain. Other nodes in blockchains will operate exactly as if normal private blockchain nodes. The idea is being able to somehow tracing over different blockchains, via "head" nodes in addition to tracing through same blockchain.

Comment: so these separated networks will have the same blockchain or different ones?

Comment: They will have different ones, my aim for that is reducing size of those blockchains.

Comment: You should look into [raiden network](http://raiden.network/) and the [polkadot multichain project](http://polkadot.io/). That's the closest I could think off. With Ethereum alone it's not possible (yet), unless you implement a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Ethereum alone it's not possible (yet), unless you implement a custom solution.

You should look into:

- [raiden network](http://raiden.network/): is a lightning network style  transaction channel network which allows payments to be securely routed across multiple peer-to-peer payment channels.
- [polkadot project](http://polkadot.io/): is a multi-chain framework that supports interoperability between wildly different chains with different properties including encrypted proof-of-authority chains suitable for internal enterprise networks.

Both a proposed to work with Ethereum but still in development. That's the closest I could think off.