# Connect private blockchain to public blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain

I need to connect my private blockchain to the public Ethereum blockchain, this is possible? Or this concept is the Consensus nodes?

Thank you,
Best Regards!

Comment: what kind of "connect" are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correct, this scenario is not possible.
Connecting from one blockchain to the blocks of another is not allowed.

You can find some useful info in [this question.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/10752/9938)